# Help identify weird mount

Tags: mount

One of the entry when I use the df command is the following... What is it?

```
/dev/loop2                    2944       2944          0 100% /snap/pulseaudio/9
```

there is this as well:

```
/dev/loop0                   83456      83456          0 100% /snap/core/2898
/dev/loop1                   83456      83456          0 100% /snap/core/2844
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those mounts points are used by Ubuntu's [Snap](https://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/snappy) Packaging system.

That is how a snap is loaded / operates.

> https://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/snappy
>
> Snaps work on any distribution or device. Snaps are faster to install,
> easier to create, safer to run, and they update automatically and
> transactionally so your app is always fresh and never broken.
>
> The public collection of snaps includes the latest and best apps from
> GitHub and beyond, so you have the whole world of Linux apps at your
> fingertips.

Comment: ok so I can just ignore this  and deactivate warnings from disk space full. thanks